# Choose from list, then Draw a line Android Studio

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-spinner

My project is about drawing a line on picture, but the user has to choose from the list that provide, then the line will be draw. the line is not similar, so every time the user choose from the list, it has to show different line.

I done with drawing the line, how to read the image, and how to show the list. The problem that I faced about how to choose from the list then present the line.

What I done it's when you run the application will present everything at the same time.

My Question is how to choose from the list then present a specific line.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView;
    Button submit;
    Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);


        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) getWindowManager()
                .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), (int) getWindowManager()
                .getDefaultDisplay().getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(1);

        // Line 1
        canvas.drawLine(80, 180, 80, 380, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(80, 380, 720, 380, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(720, 380, 720, 200, paint);

        // Line 2
        canvas.drawLine(720, 200, 720, 380, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(720, 380, 290, 380, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(290, 380, 290, 560, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(290, 560, 270, 560, paint);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, locations);
        Destenation.setAdapter(adapter);
        Destenation.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.v("item", (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
    }
```